# Validation of viewstate mac failed in IIS 7.5 and 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5

I'm getting the below error

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   web farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

When checked at the below url

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors

states the cause to be one of

Cause 1: The web application is running in a farm multi-server environment (**Mine is not running in a farm**)

Cause 2: The worker process uses the IIS 7.0 application pool identity (**I'm using IIS7.5 and Windows 2008 R2**).

Cause 3: The application pool is configured by using LoadUserProfile=false

(**I'm not using DefaulaAppPool and have a separate pool for my application 
Identity type is Custom Identity
LoadUserProfile = True**)

Cause 4: The Page.ViewStateUserKey property has an incorrect value (**no such feature is enabled for CSRF**)

**I'm targeting Dot Net version v4.0**

What could be the possible cause for the error ?

*Note: if somebody wishes to mark this as a duplicate, please think over twice.  thanks*

Comment: what version of the framework are you targeting?

Comment: do you have somethng like this in your config? `<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />`

Comment: @JohnB sorry, I'm targetting v4.0 (have updated it )

Comment: no <processmodel> entry is present @JohnB

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878900/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed?rq=1

Comment: or this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error/

Comment: @JohnB will update the outcome