# ASP .NET permmissions

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have ASP .NET website. I am trying to transfer it to a new Windows Server 2008 R2. If open website using browse from IIS it is working well. But from outside I am getting the error "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." I've checked permissions to the folder for IIS user. I use Windows Authentication mode. What is the reason of 500 error?

Comment: 500 means a logic error, not a permissions issue. Disable custom error pages `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to see full-detail error messages that will help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: I have in web.config <customErrors mode ="Off" defaultRedirect="error"/>

Comment: iisstart.htm same error. If i run browser on that server is ok, but outside 500 error.

Comment: @Dai 500 error COULD be a permissions problem. It could be that the dragons at the datacenter where the site is hosted do not have enough lava to eat! Fragk, your question does not have enough information... You need to dig a little and find at least SOMETHING!

Comment: I've checked logs. There is no any information.

Comment: Since `iisstart.htm` has the same issue I am thinking that it is not a code issue, but a IIS issue instead. Perhaps in this case the ServerFault site might be a more appropriate place to post the question

Comment: iistart is ok. I am guessing it is URL Rewrite Module problem now.

Comment: Two links to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677887/how-to-set-correct-file-permissions-for-asp-net-on-iis/16678016#16678016

Comment: ASPX was not registered properly. Using aspnet_regiis.exe -i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX was not registered properly. Using aspnet_regiis.exe -i solved it