# What security options need set for a web user to use .ttf fonts?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, file-permissions

For a asp.net/MVC website, what security options are needed to use .ttf fonts and what Group/User to I apply them to?

I have a website that uses a .pdf creator that uses .ttf fonts.  All the font files are in a font folder in the main website folder.  This all works well on my company's server, but when our client put it on their server they get permissions errors.  Specifically, "Access to the path 'C:\Site\Fonts\FontFile.ttf' is denied."  I started looking for possible differences between the two servers.  They do have some different Groups/Users, so I started looking online to figure out what Group/User was needed for asp.net.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677887/how-to-set-correct-file-permissions-for-asp-net-on-iis) helpful article explains the process.  So I looked at the app pool to see what the identity was.  It shows ApplicationPoolIdentity.  Well, this is confusing because ApplicationPoolIdentity is not an option as one of the Groups/Users to set security for.  I searched for how to figure out what it was pointing to and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions) article which featured way to complicated settings for me to be changing on a client's computer, so I decided to come here.  I did do some other research, but didn't feel the need to record it all here.

Please don't get lost in my explanations of what I tried.  I merely wanted to show you the path I went down.

My real problem is I have .ttf files that the user of the website doesn't have permission for.  What permissions does the user need and what Group/User do I assign those permissions to?

Here are some details about the site, application pool, and Groups/Users options for one of the .ttf files:

**Site**, Application pool: DefaultAppPool

**DefaultAppPool**, Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity

**File security Groups/Users**

SYSTEM: Full control, modify, read & execute, read, write

Administrators: Full control, modify, read & execute, read, write

Users: Read & execute, Read

IIS_IUSRS: Read & execute, Read

Comment: Set the files to inherit their permissions from their parent folder and remove all explicitly-declared (non-inherited) permissions.

Comment: Also ensure that IIS has a MIME type entry for the font files as that can cause unexpected errors too. Finally, verify that IIS is using the static file handler for the resource path and not sending it through the ASP.NET pipeline.