# Why my oleDb connection stirng fail in asp page but works in console program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection

The sample code below shows how my application connect to a `.xlsx` file by `OleDbConnection`. However, it works in console program but not in my asp page..
The worst things is the error message returned is

> error: Unspecified error

```
try{
     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
     string sql = null;
     MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\excFile.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';");
     MyConnection.Open();
     myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  mydebug("error:" + ex.Message);
}
```

I have no idea how to handle an Unspecified error...
Does any know how to connect oledb in asp page?

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that either/or

- the ASP.Net worker process doesn't have access to `C:\excFile.xlsx`
- <strike>Microsoft Excel is not installed on the server</strike>

This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677887/how-to-set-correct-file-permissions-for-asp-net-on-iis) may help.

Comment: For point one, I can use File.Copy(); to clone a new excFile.xlsx file, I think the asp page has enough right to access the file.

Comment: Point two is wrong, sorry didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: Point One, is that ASP.Net workers run in a less priv env than a normal user and typically cannot access files outside of the "web site".

Comment: How can I test that the asp have right to access the excel file?