# Single "Default Web Site" | Multiple applications | Undesired redirecting

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

1. Windows Server 2012 R2
2. IIS 8.x

Multiple applications hosted on the single "Default Web Site", few of which use their own App Pools while most of the applications use the DefaultAppPool.

When suddenly a few of the applications stopped working normally and simply get redirected to one particular application in the list.

What kind of setting makes this happen?

Comment: first investigate the redirect with the tools of the browser

Comment: I did investigate earlier, but the information there was not enough to solve this

Comment: take a look on that on how they hack you with a file -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288362/ive-been-hacked-evil-aspx-file-uploaded-called-aspxspy-theyre-still-trying/4289379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a tool called "HTTP Redirect" in the application settings inside IIS Manager which clearly showed the undesired destination url  present.

How that got populated is still a mystery, but on removing that value, the issue got fixed.