# Common web attacks

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, ddos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preparing an ASP.Net website for penetration testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122486/preparing-an-asp-net-website-for-penetration-testing)

How to test an already built-in website across user attacks?
I have got a Process Management System developed in .NET, now before putting it into production environment, I want to test it via some series of attacks.

I appreciate if some one could share some common attacks that are commonly applied over web applications I know some such as unauthorized access, URL embedded attacks, sql injection an so on..

Please share your experiences and recommendation, thank you.

Comment: This question is maybe to be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Checklist:

[Web Application Security Guide/Checklist](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Web_Application_Security_Guide/Checklist)

Many free tools are available, you can try out these:

- [Netsparker](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/): Netsparker Community Edition is a SQL Injection Scanner.
- [Websecurify](http://www.websecurify.com/)
- [Watcher](http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/) : Watcher is a Fiddler addon which aims to assist penetration testers in passively finding Web-application vulnerabilities.
- [Wapiti](http://www.ict-romulus.eu/web/wapiti/home): Web application vulnerability scanner / security auditor
- [N-Stalker](http://www.nstalker.com/products/editions/free/)
- [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) : Skipfish is an active web application security reconnaissance tool. It prepares an interactive sitemap for the targeted site by carrying out a recursive crawl and dictionary-based probes. The resulting map is then annotated with the output from a number of active (but hopefully non-disruptive) security checks. The final report generated by the tool is meant to serve as a foundation for professional web application security assessments.
- Scrawlr
- [x5s](http://xss.codeplex.com/): x5s is a Fiddler addon which aims to assist penetration testers in finding cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. It's main goal is to help you identify the hotspots where XSS might occur by: 1. Detecting where safe encodings were not applied to emitted user-inputs. 2. Detecting where Unicode character transformations might bypass security filters. 3. Detecting where non-shortest UTF-8 encodings might bypass security filters
- [Exploit-Me](http://labs.securitycompass.com/exploit-me/): Exploit-Me is a suite of Firefox web application security testing tools designed to be lightweight and easy to use.

[Free Web Application Security Testing Tools](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-web-application-security-testing-tools/)