# How to tell if an error captured by my global.asax was displayed on the screen of the user

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

In my Global.asax file I have a Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) which "should" capture all errors experienced by the application (correct me if I'm wrong here).

My question is, I've seen errors recorded which apparently did not "fail" in terms of my users seeing the custom error page.  So what would tell me, if anything, whether or not the type of exception actually caused the custom error page to show.

I want to get better at error handling and looking for any insight or ways to improve the user's experience.  Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this similar answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751363/how-do-i-make-a-generic-error-page-in-my-asp-net-application-so-that-it-handle/10751939#10751939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In two words:

Handle all your errors at the page, and show to the user a message for what is do wrong.

Keep the global error handler for unknown to you errors, for log them and fix them in the near future, and show a general error page to your user.

For more informations and details I have write this answer: [How do I make a "generic error" page in my ASP.NET application so that it handles errors triggered when serving that page itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751363/how-do-i-make-a-generic-error-page-in-my-asp-net-application-so-that-it-handle/10751939#10751939)