# How to display requested querystrings along with aspxerrorpath

Tags: asp.net

I have an web application in asp.net and in web.config its written

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx" />
```

Suppose i have a page `abcd.aspx`. And I have send a request in browser as `abcd.aspx?p1=cvb&p2=dfg`

Now if any error occurs its redirecting to `error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=abcd.aspx.`
But i want to pass `p1` and `p2` as well as. i.e  `error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=abcd.aspx&p1=cvb&p2=dfg`

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not, this is a part of the inside function call and you can not change it. Here is the function that make the redirect and its have the `this.Request.Path` not the full url with the parameters.

```
internal bool RedirectToErrorPage(string url, CustomErrorsRedirectMode redirectMode)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this._headersWritten)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"] != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (redirectMode == CustomErrorsRedirectMode.ResponseRewrite)
        {
            this.Context.Server.Execute(url);
        }
        else
        {
            if (url.IndexOf('?') < 0)
            {
                url = url + "?aspxerrorpath=" + HttpEncoderUtility.UrlEncodeSpaces(this.Request.Path);
            }
            this.Redirect(url, false);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

To say few more.
When you have reach at that error page you have lost control, meaning that you ether have a programming error, or some unhanding exception. That error is logged on your EventViewer, but you can also use the `Application_Error` on the global.asax to personal log it and write it to your log file.

relative:
[How to catch unhandled exceptions in an asp.net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968370/how-to-catch-unhandled-exceptions-in-an-asp-net-application/10968500#10968500)
[How do I make a "generic error" page in my ASP.NET application so that it handles errors triggered when serving that page itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751363/how-do-i-make-a-generic-error-page-in-my-asp-net-application-so-that-it-handle/10751939#10751939)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for asp.net error logging.