# Page-Wide Default exception handler

Tags: asp.net, exception

I have an ASP.NET page with lots of event handlers that look like this:

```
Private Sub btnNextEvent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextEvent.Click
    Try
        NextRegistration()            
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

That tiny try-except block is repeated in many (maybe a dozen) places.

Is there a way to define a page-wide "default" exception handler, so that I could say something like this?

```
Private Overrides Sub DefaultHanderIWishIHad(ex As Exception)
    lblError.Text = ex.Message
End Sub

Private Sub btnNextEvent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextEvent.Click
    'no need to handle here, because the default handler is just fine...
    NextRegistration()            
End Sub
```

Comment: You seriously want to put the exception message into a label? What are you using this for? Troubleshooting? That won't be so easy without the full exception trace. Try putting `ex.ToString()` into the label.

Comment: This example is simplified for the sake of discussion.  For debugging, I am just putting the error in a label.

Comment: I'd suggest, for debugging or anything else, use [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx), then just remove those try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

On a page

```
private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Application: Global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use the ELMAH http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ . Which is good and easy to configure and handle all the unhandled exception

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you get an exception and not handle on place, then you lose the control - and from there you can only redirect and log the error.

So I do not recommended to have a global error catching. Now on page there is a function that is called on exceptions, the `OnError`, but I only suggest it for close any open handlers, and not for handling any error, because as I say, when you are there you have lose the control of your page.

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnError(e);
}
```

relative: [How do I make a "generic error" page in my ASP.NET application so that it handles errors triggered when serving that page itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751363/how-do-i-make-a-generic-error-page-in-my-asp-net-application-so-that-it-handle/10751939#10751939)