# How can I create an IIS error event pop-up window?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I support a ASP.NET application that has horrible error handling logic.  If a user's workflow triggers a SQL query error on the database, the user is served an error.aspx page which displays the query error and also kicks them out of the application.  Usually the work they were performing is lost and they have to log back in and start all over.

To make matters worse none of these kick-out events or error messages are logged to any database table.  I have had to enable all of the IIS Application Pool logging and parse through the IIS Web Server Event Viewer logs to determine the time and frequently of kick-outs which I have no control over preventing.

Is there is way for me to prevent these application kick-outs?  When IIS wants to serve the error.aspx page, could I instead trigger a pop-up window "an error has been encountered" that allows the user to either gracefully back out of their work or give them to chance to copy their work before being kicked?

Thanks!

Comment: I disagree with the horrible error handling. Its yours SQL errors that you have no predict and not handle correct. Use the try/catch, use the error handling on the page... there are many ways to avoid what you say.

Comment: Take a look to that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751363/how-do-i-make-a-generic-error-page-in-my-asp-net-application-so-that-it-handle/10751939#10751939