# Why isn't ViewStateUserKey enabled by default

Tags: asp.net

ViewStateUserKey seems like a very useful feature to prevent some CSRF attacks. Why is it not enabled by default in asp.net applications?

Comment: Probably because the value used to represent the user key varies in different situations; some use Session ID, some use user name.

Answer (score 2):

I tell some thoughts about:

The `ViewStateUserKey` can break the viewstate in a valid user and as result a valid user see an error. So its better to let it out, and only advanced programmers use it and know why the view state is break and handle it if possible.

Lets give you some examples.

If you use it as it is:

```
void Page_Init (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      ViewStateUserKey = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

and see this steps.

- a valid logged in user see a GridView on a page that is not require
  logging.
- this user have left the page some time, and the logging is
  expired
- now is try to paging the gridview, and gets a viewstate break

Why, because is start the page using the `ViewStateUserKey`, but after is expired the `ViewStateUserKey` is now different (null because the user is not logged in now) and break the viewstate and at the same time this page is not required to be logged in, and not redirection is happens to ask for logging again.

With this simple example, that is really happened to me, I say that this parameter can break the view state and if this set by default is may lead to some issues like that.

relative: 
[ViewStateUserKey + shared hosting + ViewStateMac validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862258/viewstateuserkey-shared-hosting-viewstatemac-validation-failure)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ViewStateUserKeyMakesViewStateMoreTamperresistant.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972969.aspx

### Conclusion from experience.

If you use this key for any page that is not request login, and you are just in other pages logged in, this can easy create viewstate error on post back and break the page, and the post back. So you can not have it enable by default - and the one that use it must know this case I describe above.