# Validation of viewstate mac failed - but only on occasion

Tags: asp.net

I am getting validation of view state MAC failing but only very very occasionally.

I am not in a web farm and can't recreate this.

Are there any known factors that can make view state MAC validation fail?

Comment: see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821243/cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-and-validation/2551810#2551810

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft blogger Tess Ferrandez has a [pretty good post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/17/asp-net-viewstate-error-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed.aspx) on this:

> Viewstate and viewstate validation use a couple of hidden form fields
>   like __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION.  If the page renders so slowly
>   that the __EVENTVALIDATION field has not rendered by the time someone
>   clicks the button or control that causes the postback, ASP.NET will
>   also believe that the viewstate is invalid and report this.

Check whether your viewstate is very large in the problematic page(s).  You may want to turn off `EnableViewState` property on controls that don't need it, especially large databound controls that don't need to remember their state between postbacks.