# I'm getting an "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string" error in generated temp file?

Tags: debugging, umbraco, visual-studio-debugging

As the title suggests, I'm getting this error when I run the project from Visual Studio locally at runtime. It builds just fine.

> ***Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.***
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.FormatException: Invalid length for a
>   Base-64 char array or string.

Unlike the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555249/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array-during-decoding-decryption) [scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858761/what-causing-this-invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array) I've read about with [marked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925729/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930855/invalid-viewstate-invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array-or-string) (there are 4 links here), my error's source file comes from a generated temp file.

> **Source Error:**
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> **Source File:** c:\Users\tessa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\1edc00ec\dbb0fa2f\App_Web_default.master.a29f75f4.tl5zweer.0.cs
>   Line: 0

So I've checked out that source file. I'm confused as to how it could be line 0, but on the first line, it refers to an Umbraco master page (x'd out for privacy).

```
#pragma checksum "C:\Team Projects\xxxxxx-tfs2012\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx Responsive Boilerplate\Main\xxxxxxxxx Responsive Boilerplate-xx\xxxxxxxxx Responsive Boilerplate\umbraco\masterpages\default.master" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "079A4F7CAEE49CF6EE4209E18039C993A74D1D19"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34014
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know why Umbraco is causing this error, if it even is? I see a lot of talk about "ViewState", but I don't really know what that is. I'm just front-end on this project, and the back-end devs are too busy to look into this.

Let me know if you need more information to help you help me solve this bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was an issue local to my machine. My co-developers confirmed that they could, in fact, compile and run the code without the error when they pulled it from the server. I'm not sure exactly what happened, how, or why, but I ended up debugging 101 style, by turning it off and on again.

When it rebooted, I got a nifty error about a broken trust relationship. I called a guy from our IT department, and he fixed that by removing my machine from our domain and adding it back in.

When I finally did get back in, I ran the code and the error was gone.

I'm not sure how the two issues are related, if they ever were. But something in that process fixed it. Thanks, everyone!