# Prevent error message : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

How to prevent this error in aspx page in c# ?

```
Message: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
```

On this **code behind** line :

```
byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
```

In `Google search` I have find this:

The problem seems to be with the ViewState.

The ViewState is encrypted, and when an attempt is made to decrypt it on postback, the error is triggered.

I have tried this solution in the **web.config** file, on set ViewState not to be encrypted **without success**, like this:

```
<system.web>
<pages viewStateEncryptionMode=”Never”>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821243/cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-and-validation/2551810#2551810

Comment: if the viewstate is too large, maybe its cuts out on post back, maybe you need to split it or compress it, or both... find out why is corrupted as first step.