# What else can cause 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" exception with WebResource.axd?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, iis-6

Recently, a couple of my applications have started throwing exceptions with the message `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed` intermitently

My applications already have a machineKey specified in the web.config as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309859/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-exception-on-webresource-axd)

The applications are deployed to a *single* Windows 2003 server running IIS6.

Comment: Same problem here, same list of solutions including setting up the axd extension in IIS and setting the registry to switch off EnableExtensionlessUrls when you have .NET 4.0 installed (even though it's a v3.5 site).

While those did give some improvements, it didn't blat the lot.

Answer (score 1):

Usually on webResource.axd this is happens because the key that follows the webResource.axd on the url, have been convert to lowercase from the crawler, or in general changed

Comment: I take it this is not something that can be avoided?

Comment: @BigChrisDid5 depends from where this message appears. If there are from webresource.asd you do not need to do something, just check the computer ip that makes it what it is (crawler, hacker...) If this message is coming from a page then is some think that you can do to avoid it.