# My site's error log is filled with the errors related to ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net

My Site's error log is filled with these errors:-

This is an invalid script resource request.
Invalid viewstate.
Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

All these errors are appearing at least 100 times a day.

After doing some RnD on internet i have done following things:-

1- define machine key in my web config.
2- created robots.txt file and add ScriptResource.axd file in that.

Can some one guide me what I am missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Possible Reason
   I have see some crawlers that **remove the verify key** on the end of the files, or convert **it to small case**, so this have as result to get this error.
2. Second Possible Reason
   Some one test and search your pages for weak points and entry ways to your back data.

**On the log you can see how they call the ScriptResource.axd** and what is the problem on the key. And check what ip make this calls - is the same ?

Some reference.

["Padding is Invalid and cannot be removed" exception on WebResource.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309859/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-exception-on-webresource-axd)

[CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed and Validation of viewstate MAC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821243/cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-and-validation-o/2551810#2551810)

one more, I do not think that its need to add ScriptResource.axd on robots and remove it from search (I mean that this is not actually the problem) - how ever its not bad idea.

Comment: i will try to check what is mentioned in your answer and let you know. Thanks for answer

Comment: I have implemented all the things which are mentioned in articles above. Now rate of error is reduced i.e. previously those errors were appearing 100+ times a day and now they are appearing around 10-30 times a day. Any other suggestions.

Comment: @Zeeshan Umar you do not need to reduce them to zero. If the error come from the crawler then you have nothing to do.

Comment: I am still getting daily around 40-50 errors. This rate is too high. can someone help me.

Comment: @Zeeshan can you check the ip that comming from ? if its the same, then its a crawler that read false your page.