# ASP.NET: Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: asp.net

I have a WizardStep Control from which i need one information: The total amount from a webshop cart. As i searched and asked this forum my conclusion was that this couldn't be done by passing a hiddenfield or a hidden textbox value to the next page from a WizardStep Complete step. So i tried to put this information into a session then directed to a new page where i make a form textbox whos value would be the session value.

But i get the Validation of viewstate MAC failed error. I have tried to delay the submit call by 3 seconds, but that itn't help and i dont run the site at a webfarm.

The reason that i need the textbox is that my payment gateway requires that i pass the total amount through form values.

Here is the page that my wizard control directs to. Its just a test page atm. Right now i just need to transfer a value from the textbox to the next page without the viewstate error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout('submitForm()', 3000);

    }

    function submitForm() {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>

<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the viewstate error occurs because a page is refreshed before it is finished loading as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121579/im-getting-a-strange-unhandled-exception-from-my-asp-net-application-validatio).  Given that this is a simple page to just redirect the data, I would ensure you are using an HTML input element, and not an ASP TextBox control (or any other ASP controls), which should completely remove the viewstate from the page.