# Validation of viewstate MAC failed. while submitting a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am getting the below error when submitting an asp.net page using javascript. I have set

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never"
EnableViewState="false"
EnableViewStateMac="false"
```

in my page directive

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that `<machineKey>` configuration specifies the same `validationKey` and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: You're not in a webfarm scenarion ? Can you post the whole first line of your aspx file ? are you sure this is the one getting executed ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because your viewstate times out, a security feature.
I wouldn't play around with the machine key, have you set the enableViewStateMac="False"  right on your .aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally get this error with sites I have hosted with GoDaddy. I do one or all of the following:

- Recompile and reupload your binary file
- Call the hosting company and tell them what's going on. Sometimes it's an issue on their end
- Wait it out. Sometimes it will just go away. But still call your hosting company.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121579/im-getting-a-strange-unhandled-exception-from-my-asp-net-application-validatio).